# duplicate entries in database while using save_post or wp_insert_post

Tags: wpdb, wp-insert-post, save-post

*Here is what I am trying to do* - I have created a custom table in the database and I am trying to enter data into it everytime a post is created. The database-entry needs to happen **ONCE AND ONLY WHEN A NEW POST IS CREATED**. NOT on post-update, revision, status-change etc. FYI, new posts created are always put to `draft` status and then published later. Data that is inserted into the table is metadata of the created post, that is a post-meta-key and its post-meta-value. I need this custom data to be in a separate table.

*This is what I have tried* -
I am not sure what specific wp-hook I should be hooking into to perform this function. After some research here is some code that I have cooked up, that uses `wp_insert_post()`.

```
function update_profile_record( $post_id ) {

                //if ($post->post_type = 'post') return;
                $pro_realname = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'realname', true );
                $pro_cell = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cell', true );
                $pro_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'e_mail', true );
                $pro_subdate = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'submit_date', true );
                if ($pro_subdate == '') { $pro_subdate = get_the_date( $format, $post_id ); }

                    global $wpdb;
                    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "profile_record";
                    $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array(
                    'rec_profile_name' => $pro_realname,
                    'rec_profile_contact' => $pro_cell,
                    'rec_profile_email' => $pro_email,
                    'rec_profile_date' => $pro_subdate
                    ));
            }
        add_action(  'wp_insert_post',  'update_profile_record', 10, 1 );
```

---

### UPDATE

*Here is what is happening* - This code using `wp_insert_post` helps make entries into database without a hitch, the problem is everytime any post is updated, a duplicate entry is inserted into the db. The solution provided by @s_ha_dum in the answer results in empty values in the custom table.

According to [post transition status](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), I have also tried `{auto-draft}_to_{draft}`, `{new}_to_{draft}`, `{new}_{post}` but it does not fill up any data in the table. So my question is, is there a specific hook for the function I am trying to achieve or I will need to rely on `save_post/wp_insert_post` only alongwith if_else statements.

---

```
Here is the order of how it needs to happen :
```

1. **A new post is created** and put to draft status, alongwith the custom meta data ( Metadata is now available in the DB, so now it is available to be copied to custom table in DB ).
2. Once metadata is available, our **function runs and updates** the values to custom table.

If I am not wrong here, looks like my function needs to run just after the post is created, needs to run only once and should not be affected with any sort of post updates.

---

UPDATE : Since I did not get a solution, I took an alternative route. Thanks @s_ha_dum for trying though.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but I'm certain this exact question has been asked and answered before here if you look around.

Comment: @Milo i have been and still looking around.

Answer (score 1):

[`wp_insert_post` runs when a post is updated as well](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3552). If you [scan the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3094) you will see numerous blocks of code switching between an update or not an update. In fact, [`wp_update_post()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.2.2/src/wp-includes/post.php#L3570) just passes data, after a little processing, to `wp_insert_post()` for the bulk of the work. That is why your code runs more than you think it should-- the hook doesn't work as you think it should. Fortunately, WordPress passes a parametere telling you if the hook is being used on an update or not.

```
do_action( 'wp_insert_post', $post_ID, $post, $update );
```

So...

```
function update_profile_record( $post_ID, $post, $update ) {
  if (true == $update) return;

  //if ($post->post_type = 'post') return;
  $pro_realname = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'realname', true );
  $pro_cell = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'cell', true );
  $pro_email = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'e_mail', true );
  $pro_subdate = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'submit_date', true );
  if ($pro_subdate == '') { 
    $pro_subdate = get_the_date( $format, $post_id ); 
  }

  global $wpdb;
  $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "profile_record";
  $wpdb->insert( 
    $table_name, 
    array(
      'rec_profile_name' => $pro_realname,
      'rec_profile_contact' => $pro_cell,
      'rec_profile_email' => $pro_email,
      'rec_profile_date' => $pro_subdate,
    )
  );
}
add_action(  'wp_insert_post',  'update_profile_record', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: any idea why the code is logging empty values in the database ?

Comment: I think the values are not yet available in the database when this action runs.